# Como sumar SOLO la parte numerica a un digito?

Tags: javascript

```js
var a = "20px";

setInterval(function(){

a += 20;
console.log(a);
},1000);
```

***Como podria sumarle solo a la parte numerica? , ya que con mi codigo queda como string***

Comment: Usa **a = parseFloat(a)** ya que es solo un número

Comment: La pregunta sería ¿como sumar la parte numérica de un `string`? Porque un dígito es un número que se expresa con una sola cifra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con `parseInt` puedes lograrlo:

```js
var a = "20px"; 

setInterval(function(){ 
a = (parseInt(a) + 20) + "px"; 
console.log(a); 
},1000);
```

[Segun la documentacion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):

> Si parseInt encuentra un carácter que no es un numeral en la base
>   especificada, lo ignora y todos los caracteres sucesivos y devuelve el
>   valor entero analizado hasta ese punto. parseInt trunca los números a
>   valores enteros. Se permiten espacios iniciales y finales.

En otras palabras, analizara el string "10px" y cuando encuentre el caracter "p" se detendra y te retornara los primeros caracteres que si son digitos, en este caso 10, como tipo inte[ger.

Comment: No quiero perder el "px"

Comment: agregalo en el console.log(a + "px");

Comment: Mira la respuesta actualizada

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar cortando la cadena, siempre y cuando sepas que texto vendrá dentro.

Luego conviertes el número a entero o flotante dependiendo lo que necesites, y haces tu operación.

Ej.

```js
var tamanio = '20px';
var cantidad = tamanio.split("px");
var suma = parseInt(cantidad[0])+10;

console.log(suma);
```

Comment: no quiero perder el px y tampoco saber donde está el digito

Comment: Entonces si no quieres hacer ninguna operacion crea otra variable, una donde guardes el numero y otra que tipo es `px`, etc

Answer (score 0):

### EDIT

Dado que quieres conservar los dos valores, un simple `replace` bastaría para obtener cada valor por separado.

Luego puedes convertir el resultado `numero` a entero usando el operador unario + (o bien mediante otro método)  y hacer la suma.

```js
var string = "20px";
var numero = string.replace(/\D/g, "");
var letras = string.replace(/[^a-z]/gi, "");   

document.write("Número extraido: "+numero+"<br>");
document.write("Texto extraido: "+letras+"<br>");
var a = +numero+20;
document.write("Suma: "+a);
```

Comment: no quiero perder el px